# How can avoid Adding twice in vb

Tags: vb.net

Hi guys I'm trying to dispay message if the same Id exists in the database. but If statement does not work with OleDb.OleDbDataAdapte
how can I solve this problem and make If statement works ?

```
If Da1 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Payments where BookingID = " &
         CInt(txtBookingID.Text) & "", Con1) Then

     MessageBox.Show("This Bill for this Booking is existed in the system. 
     You Can not add it again.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
     MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

else 

    new_rec("BookingID") = txtBookingID.Text
    new_rec("DateAndTime") = lblDateAndTime.Text

    Dt1.Rows.Add(new_rec)
    Da1.Update(Dt1)

    MessageBox.Show("Booking ID " + " *" + txtBookingID.Text + "*  " + 
    "has been Saved to The System.      Press * OK * to Go Back")

end if
```

Comment: This code uses a technique that is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. If the same technique is used elsewhere in the app, it's practically begging to get hacked.

Comment: Also: **you never execute the query**. Just creating a data adapter doesn't run the sql command. You have to **Fill()** a dataset or datatable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to avoid adding or inserting information twice to access database in Visual Basic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27447985/how-to-avoid-adding-or-inserting-information-twice-to-access-database-in-visual)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
 Da1 = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from Payments", Con1)

da1.Fill(dt1)

If dt1 is nothing orelse dt1.select("boolingid=" & txtBookingID.Text).count > 0  Then

    MessageBox.Show("This Bill for this Booking is existed in the system. You 
    Can not add it again.", "Authentication Failure", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
    MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)

else 

    new_rec("BookingID") = txtBookingID.Text
    new_rec("DateAndTime") = lblDateAndTime.Text

    Dt1.Rows.Add(new_rec)
    Da1.Update(Dt1)

    MessageBox.Show("Booking ID " + " *" + txtBookingID.Text + "*  " + 
    "has been Saved to The System.  Press * OK * to Go Back")
end if
```

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR REPLY. BUT THIS WILL NOT ALLOW TO ADD. IT always do the if and dose not  go to else statement

Comment: @EssaAlatwan not Clear Show with example. if you have that id in table then show warning otherwise store. That's right ah?

Comment: yes that what I want.  If the Id exist in the table, show warning otherwise should store the information in new row.